# Can I control the size and placement of an Inputpanel in .NET CF?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, soft-input-panel

I am trying to set the size, at Design Time, of the input panel but cannot figure out if it's even possible.

`inputPanel.Bounds` doesn't have a setter....it's so **stinking tiny** I don't know how useful it will be on our touch screen.
Am I missing something?
How has anyone else given there users a touch friendly on screen keyboard on a Windows CE device?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Windows Mobile device, the standard SIP (software input panel) of the MS build ditribution is mostly in use. This one is small and should be used with a 'pencil'. This SIP is also always docked to the menu bar and can not be resized nor moved.

[image: WM standard SIP]

There are alternatives which are sometimes set as default SIP, like Honeywell does with there Dolphin black. This device running WM65 shows a SIP similar to Android.

[image: WM custom SIP]

Windows CE devices mostly come with the SIP provided with platform builder. This SIP is moveable but can also not be resized.

There are other, 3rd party, Software Keyboards available or you can write a custom one yourself: DVORAK SIP [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158734.aspx] or SPB Keyboard [http://spb.com/pocketpc-software/keyboard/download.html], Intermec SIP/Keyboard Designer [http://webapps.intermec.com/EFulfillment/SoftwareListForm.aspx?SoftwareID=2416].

You need to know what the difference between WinCE and WM is. I assume you are talking about a WM and not a WinCE device.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  A little off-topic, but I wanted to point out that you can p/invoke to move the SIP in WM.  I've done it in an app such that if a text fiewld was getting keyed into at the bottom of the screen the SIP docked to the top instead.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer!  I do know the difference and I am talking about WinCE.  6 to be exact.  Your answer pretty much confirms what I found since I asked this question.  If you want a sizable, touch friendly, on screen keyboard be prepared to invest tons of time of rely on a 3rd party.  I think we are going to give Resco.net a shot on that front.

Comment: @tcarvin Yes, you can do nearly everything using native code, but resizing a foreign window that is not prepared for resizing would be a hard aproach. Thanks for the hint. Resizing the SIP would require also re-position of all buttons (keys).